# Is there a way to take a screenshot of a failure automatically during Automation of a website?

Tags: php, behat, gitlab-ci-runner, gherkin, mink

All my automation scripts must run during the midnight and I see failures in the report the next day morning and not able to reproduce and my raised issues to developers are getting rejected as non-producible. I want to set up an environment which will be capable of taking screenshots of the web page after a failed step.
* Code is written in Gherkin Language
* We use default Mink functions and some custom PHP functions
* We use Gitlab and Gitlab runners for execution

I'm new to to Behat and PHP. So, I haven't tried anything yet.

- Ideally I would love to see the screenshots of failures with the name of the image the particular line or some sort of unique identifier.
- The Images can be saved to a repository [Cloud/gitlab/Local system]

Comment: I believe the issue here is that I'm not using a dockerized version/ Github. I'm using gitlab. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Add an [after step hook](http://behat.org/en/latest/user_guide/context/hooks.html#hooks) that can handle that.

Then on the hook you just take a screenshot.

Found a piece of code [here](https://rockhopper.dk/linux/software/behat-taking-screenshots-of-failed-steps/) which might help you.

```php
    /**
     * @AfterStep
     */
    public function takeScreenshotAfterFailedStep(AfterStepScope $scope)
    {
        if (TestResult::FAILED === $scope->getTestResult()->getResultCode()) {
            $driver = $this->minkContext->getSession()->getDriver();

            if (!$driver instanceof Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver) {
                return;
            }

            $page               = $this->minkContext->getSession()->getPage()->getContent();
            $screenshot         = $driver->getScreenshot();
            $screenshotFileName = date('d-m-y').'-'.uniqid().'.png';
            $pageFileName       = date('d-m-y').'-'.uniqid().'.html';
            // NOTE: hardcoded path:
            $filePath           = "/var/www/symfony.dev/";

            file_put_contents($filePath.$screenshotFileName, $screenshot);
            file_put_contents($filePath.$pageFileName, $page);
            print 'Screenshot at: '.$filePath.$screenshotFileName."\n";
            print 'HTML dump at: '.$filePath.$pageFileName."\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: Hi, It failed with this error
Behat\Testwork\Call\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 1 passed to FeatureContext::takeScreenshotAfterFailedStep() must be an instance of AfterStepScope, instance of Behat\Behat\Hook\Scope\AfterStepScope given in

Answer (score 0):

A lot ready to use extensions are available in Behat, just like the way you are making use of the Mink library to mimic user's interaction with the browser. Similarly, there is a screenshot extension too available which captures screenshots for failed steps. You can find the details here - https://packagist.org/packages/bex/behat-screenshot

Comment: Added
"require-dev": {
        "behat/behat": "^3.3.1",
        "bex/behat-screenshot"
default:
  extensions:
    Bex\Behat\ScreenshotExtension:
      image_drivers:
        local:
          screenshot_directory: C:./Temp/GitFails
          clear_screenshot_directory: true
But failed with this exception:
In ExtensionManager.php line 194:
                                                                                 
  [Behat\Testwork\ServiceContainer\Exception\ExtensionInitializationException]   
  `Bex\Behat\ScreenshotExtension` extension file or class could not be located.

Answer (score 0):

This did the job for me:

```
public function takeScreenshotAfterFailedStep(AfterStepScope $scope) {

    try {    

       $session =  $this->getSession();

       if (99 === $scope->getTestResult()->getResultCode()) {
          $stepName = $scope->getStep()->getText();   
          $this->takeScreenshot($stepName);
          echo "\n\nYour test may have failed - ";
          echo "\nCurrent Page URL: ". $session->getCurrentUrl();
       }
    } catch(Exception $e) {

        $e_msg = "Something went wrong when taking screenshots";
        throw new Exception($e_msg, $e->getCode(), $e);
    }

} 

public function takeScreenshot($stepName=null) {

    echo "The current working directory:  " . getcwd() . "\n";

    $filePath = getcwd();      // default path

    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');    
    $fileName =   'screenshot-' . uniqid() . '_' . date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') .'.png';

    # if directory path is specified in Behat yml, use it.
    if (isset($this->parameters['screen_shot_path'])) {
       $filePath = $this->parameters['screen_shot_path'];
    }

    $this->saveScreenshot($fileName, $filePath);
    echo "\nScreenshot taken -> " . $fileName . "\n";
}
```